# Sqldependency vs CDC for writing a data replicator from sql server to mongodb

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, sqldependency, change-data-capture

I would like to write a simple replicator that replicates data from a sql server database to mongodb database.

1. What are my options other than:

   a) Change Data Capture

   b) SqlDependency
2. What is impact of each the options on sql-server db performance?
3. If I have 50 writes/min on a table which option would be a better candidate and why?
4. Which option would be a better one for recovery in case of a problem occur and machine/server reboots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDC (+Change Tracking) and SqlDependency solve different problems and address different scenarios. SqlDependency is a cache invalidation mechanism for application. It is unsuitable for tracking changes. CDC is explicitly targeting applications that need to track changes. It is pretty much the *only* viable mechanism to track changes. Consuming the tracked changes is up to your application, like writing them to `/dev/null` or modngodb (same thing, actually).

Please read the MSDN relevant topics first, start from [Track Data Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx).

Comment: LOL /dev/null = mongodb

Answer (score 1):

I like CDC for this type of operation for a couple of different reasons

1. You can configure it to capture net changes. If you don't care that a given row was updated 10 times within your capture interval, this is the way to go.
2. It tells you *what* changed. You can see which columns changed in which operation.
3. You don't need to track all of the columns. If there's a column that you don't need to propagate to your downstream data store (in your case, MongoDB), then don't include it in the tracking.
4. It's asynchronous. CDC uses a log reader to determine what changes happened after the fact so you don't need to slow down your primary application for CDC.

Answer (score 0):

To complete previous answers :

- CDC is not available in SQL Server standard edition
- One option can be to use table triggers + Servier Broker (available in standard edition).
- An other option can be to use Change tracking (CT) to monitor table changes (available in standard edition) and a custom monitoring app to propagate changes to MongoDb. I used CT in production environment to implement a homemade replication system, it works really fine. Ressource overcost to maintain CT index is similar to a non-clusterd index according to MS.

Hope it helps